How to add themeswitcher(from MUI) globally
I am new to react and building a React app using Material-UI (MUI v5) and have implemented routing using React Router. I want to include a theme switcher(which is present in SignUp and SignIn MUI Templates) that allows toggling between Light, Dark, and System modes globally . However, the theme switcher doesn’t seem to work as expected, and the theme isn’t applied consistently across all pages when i am trying to do so.
index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home';
import SignIn from './sign-in/SignIn';
import SignUp from './sign-up/SignUp';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    <Routes>
      <Route path = "/" element={<Home/>}/>
      <Route path = "sign-up" element={<SignUp/>}/>
      <Route path = "sign-in" element={<SignIn/>}/>
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();


SignUp.js
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import FormLabel from '@mui/material/FormLabel';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import MuiCard from '@mui/material/Card';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import AppTheme from '../shared-theme/AppTheme';
import ColorModeSelect from '../shared-theme/ColorModeSelect';
import { GoogleIcon, FacebookIcon } from './CustomIcons';


const Card = styled(MuiCard)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  alignSelf: 'center',
  width: '100%',
  padding: theme.spacing(4),
  gap: theme.spacing(2),
  margin: 'auto',
  boxShadow:
    'hsla(220, 30%, 5%, 0.05) 0px 5px 15px 0px, hsla(220, 25%, 10%, 0.05) 0px 15px 35px -5px',
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: '450px',
  },
  ...theme.applyStyles('dark', {
    boxShadow:
      'hsla(220, 30%, 5%, 0.5) 0px 5px 15px 0px, hsla(220, 25%, 10%, 0.08) 0px 15px 35px -5px',
  }),
}));

const SignUpContainer = styled(Stack)(({ theme }) => ({
  height: 'calc((1 - var(--template-frame-height, 0)) * 100dvh)',
  minHeight: '100%',
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    padding: theme.spacing(4),
  },
  '&::before': {
    content: '""',
    display: 'block',
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: -1,
    inset: 0,
    backgroundImage:
      'radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 50%, hsl(210, 100%, 97%), hsl(0, 0%, 100%))',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    ...theme.applyStyles('dark', {
      backgroundImage:
        'radial-gradient(at 50% 50%, hsla(210, 100%, 16%, 0.5), hsl(220, 30%, 5%))',
    }),
  },
}));

export default function SignUp(props) {
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = React.useState(false);
  const [emailErrorMessage, setEmailErrorMessage] = React.useState('');
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = React.useState(false);
  const [passwordErrorMessage, setPasswordErrorMessage] = React.useState('');
  const [nameError, setNameError] = React.useState(false);
  const [nameErrorMessage, setNameErrorMessage] = React.useState('');

  const validateInputs = () => {
    const email = document.getElementById('email');
    const password = document.getElementById('password');
    const name = document.getElementById('name');

    let isValid = true;

    if (!email.value || !/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email.value)) {
      setEmailError(true);
      setEmailErrorMessage('Please enter a valid email address.');
      isValid = false;
    } else {
      setEmailError(false);
      setEmailErrorMessage('');
    }

    if (!password.value || password.value.length < 6) {
      setPasswordError(true);
      setPasswordErrorMessage('Password must be at least 6 characters long.');
      isValid = false;
    } else {
      setPasswordError(false);
      setPasswordErrorMessage('');
    }

    if (!name.value || name.value.length < 1) {
      setNameError(true);
      setNameErrorMessage('Name is required.');
      isValid = false;
    } else {
      setNameError(false);
      setNameErrorMessage('');
    }

    return isValid;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (nameError || emailError || passwordError) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    console.log({
      name: data.get('name'),
      lastName: data.get('lastName'),
      email: data.get('email'),
      password: data.get('password'),
    });
  };

  return (
    <AppTheme {...props}>
      <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
      <ColorModeSelect sx={{ position: 'fixed', top: '1rem', right: '1rem' }} />
      <SignUpContainer direction="column" justifyContent="space-between">
        <Card variant="outlined">
        <div class="logo"></div>
          <Typography
            component="h1"
            variant="h4"
            sx={{ width: '100%', fontSize: 'clamp(2rem, 10vw, 2.15rem)' }}
          >
            Sign up
          </Typography>
          <Box
            component="form"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: 2 }}
          >
            <FormControl>
              <FormLabel htmlFor="name">Full name</FormLabel>
              <TextField
                autoComplete="name"
                name="name"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="name"
                placeholder="Jon Snow"
                error={nameError}
                helperText={nameErrorMessage}
                color={nameError ? 'error' : 'primary'}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl>
              <FormLabel htmlFor="email">Email</FormLabel>
              <TextField
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                placeholder="your@email.com"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                variant="outlined"
                error={emailError}
                helperText={emailErrorMessage}
                color={passwordError ? 'error' : 'primary'}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl>
              <FormLabel htmlFor="password">Password</FormLabel>
              <TextField
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                placeholder="••••••"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="new-password"
                variant="outlined"
                error={passwordError}
                helperText={passwordErrorMessage}
                color={passwordError ? 'error' : 'primary'}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox value="allowExtraEmails" color="primary" />}
              label="I want to receive updates via email."
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              onClick={validateInputs}
            >
              Sign up
            </Button>
          </Box>
          <Divider>
            <Typography sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>or</Typography>
          </Divider>
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: 2 }}>
            <Button
              fullWidth
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={() => alert('Sign up with Google')}
              startIcon={<GoogleIcon />}
            >
              Sign up with Google
            </Button>
            <Button
              fullWidth
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={() => alert('Sign up with Facebook')}
              startIcon={<FacebookIcon />}
            >
              Sign up with Facebook
            </Button>
            <Typography sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
              Already have an account?{' '}
              <Link
                href="/sign-in/"
                variant="body2"
                sx={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
              >
                Sign in
              </Link>
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Card>
      </SignUpContainer>
    </AppTheme>
  );
}


I think the theme switcher is from colormodeselect component which I am attaching here,
ColorModeSelect.js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useColorScheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function ColorModeSelect(props) {
  const { mode, setMode } = useColorScheme();
  if (!mode) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Select
      value={mode}
      onChange={(event) => setMode(event.target.value)}
      SelectDisplayProps={{
        'data-screenshot': 'toggle-mode',
      }}
      {...props}
    >
      <MenuItem value="system">System</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="light">Light</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="dark">Dark</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  );
}


Please guide me with the changes I have to do
I had tried
Wrapping the entire app with ThemeProvider.
Adding the ColorModeSelect component to the App and Home components.

If you wrapped your <App /> with <ThemeProvider theme={theme} /> already. The color mode Select should be working for all the pages. Can you create a code sandbox or public repo to investigate what's happening?
